# Saving select box value to database laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm doing my first site in laravel 5 (recently updated from 4.2, and still getting used to it), and I have a view with a select box and I can't get the input data.

The view:

```
{!!Form::select('estado', array(
'obra' => 'Obra', 
'licitacion' => 'Licitación', 
'oficial' => 'oficial'), null, ['id' =>'estado' class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

In the Controller I do

```
data = Input::all();
```

But, if I do dd to the data array the field doesn't appear in it
(every field is there but the one in the select box)

In my model I have it in the rules as required.
My question is, what am I doing wrong, that I can't save the value,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this was really basic stuff, but I figured out, all I had to do was type the following commands in the root of the proyect:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear:cache
```

And everything it's working now